# How can I eager load a group of relations that was previously specified within model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple cards that belong to the user model. Like vendor, customer and admin and so on. I  can eager load them typically like:

```
User::with(['admin', 'vendor', 'customer'])->get();
```

but this cards are changeable, there could be added some more. In that case I don't want to make that change everywhere where I used to eager load that group. Instead I want something like

```
User::withCards()->get();
```

And in model itself something like:

```
protected $cards = ['admin','vendor', 'customer'];

public function withCards(){
    return $this->with($this->cards);
}
```

Well I tried that without luck. But I think with the example above you understand what I meaning. How could I accomplish something like that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: @KurtFriars that was it. Could I have that as an answer please?

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [local query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes). You can achieve this using:

```
protected $cards = ['admin','vendor', 'customer'];

public function scopeWithCards($query){
    return $query->with($this->cards);
}
```